# qmake is not an executable

Tags: python, qt

I am trying to install pyqt on OS X but getting

```
configure.py: error: '/Users/Chris/Qt5.4/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake'
is not an executable
```

I am following the instructions on a site which tells me to:

```
cd /var/tmp
cp /Users/gvincent/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz .
cp /Users/gvincent/Downloads/sip-4.15.5.tar.gz .
tar xvf PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvf sip-4.15.5.tar.gz
cd sip-4.15.5/
python3 configure.py -d ~/.env/ariane_mail/lib/python3.4/site-packages --arch x86_64
make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
cd ../PyQt-gpl-5.2.1/
python3 configure.py --destdir ~/.env/ariane_mail/lib/python3.4/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake
make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
~/.env/ariane_mail/bin/python -c "import PyQt5"**
```

The part that's giving me the error is the

```
python3 configure.py --destdir ~/.env/ariane_mail/lib/python3.4/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it says just what it says: `qmake` is not an executable. Check `qmake`'s attributes and user permissions using `ls`, `chmod` and `chown` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python 3 installed, you can simply install [`PyQT5`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) from the terminal using `pip3 install PyQt5 --user`.

Answer (score -1):

Use "$HOME" instead of "~" let me passed it.